# compute the value of Complex integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let C be the contour|z|= 1 traversed once counter-clockwise and a ∈R.
(a)  Compute the value of the integral ∫$\frac{e^{(iaz)}}{z^2}$dz.
(b)  Use  your  answer  to  part  (a)  to  compute  the  values  of  the
integrals ∫(from 0 to 2π) $e^{(−asinθ)}$cos(a cosθ−θ)dθ,
and
∫(from 0 to2π)e$^{(−asinθ)}$sin(acosθ−θ)dθ.

My solution:
for part (a) I applied Cauchy integral theorem and got =2πi$f'(0)$= -2πa.
and for part(b) by putting z= e$^{iθ}$= cosθ+i sinθ., dz=i e$^{iθ}$ dθ.
i get $\frac {e^{aicosθ-asinθ} (ie^{iθ})dθ}{e^{2iθ}}$;
$\frac {(e^{aicosθ}.e^{asinθ})i dθ}{e^{iθ}}$;$\frac {(cos(acosθ+isin(acosθ)e^{-asinθ})idθ}{e^{iθ}}$.
This is where im stuck at.. i cant figure out how to get just $θ$ instead of $isin(acosθ)$. Am i missing any formula or shortcut or trick i can use there?

Comment: $\Re(\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{(iaz)}}{z^2}dz)=\int_0^{2\pi} \Re(e^{i a e^{it}}e^{-it} i)dt$

Comment: that exactly was my first step to solve part(b)

Comment: You didn't make appear what they asked : $i a e^{it} = i a (\cos(t)+i \sin(t))$

Comment: yes.. i missed that step and directly multiplied ia inside the bracket and got my first written term.

Comment: What about (c) : use (b) to solve the same integrals with $a \in \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: `$\Re(\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{(iaz)}}{z^2}dz)=\int_0^{2\pi} \Re(e^{i a e^{it}}e^{-it} i)dt$`

Comment: so you saying change thetas in part b to change to z ? and then try to solve it?

Comment: I'm saying $$\Re(\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{(iaz)}}{z^2}dz)=\int_0^{2\pi} \Re(e^{i a e^{it}}e^{-it} i)dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \Re(e^{i a \cos (t) - a \sin(t)}e^{-it} i)dt$$ which is close to the integral they asked. Then I'm saying you can use analytic continuation to find the result of those integrals also for $a$ complex.

Comment: What do you not understand ? $\Re(e^{i a \cos (t) - a \sin(t)}e^{-it} i) = ?\quad$   (and try using mathjax correctly, I've shown above the relevant code)

Comment: yes i got it.. is my part (a) correct with cauchy integral theorem?